# LayoutConstraint error when programmatically setting dynamic uiimageview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, autolayout

I have a UIImageView position that is dependent on iAdBanner appears. I'm getting error :

```
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x17409eb40 UIImageView:0x1741e9200.bottom == UIView:0x17418d270.bottom - 100>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x174281e00 UIImageView:0x1741e9200.bottom == UIView:0x17418d270.bottom - 50>"
```

Any ideas on what's causing this? Below is code to set uiimageview and depending on whether iAd loads or not, it's height is set.

```
    UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"sunshine.png"]];
    CGRect frame = imgView.frame;
    frame.size.width = 180;
    frame.size.height = 30;
    imgView.frame = frame;
    imgView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

    [imgView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
    [imgView sizeToFit];
    [self.view addSubview:imgView];

    [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint
                              constraintWithItem:imgView
                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
                              relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                              toItem:self.view
                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
                              multiplier:1.0
                              constant:6.0]];
    _imgView = imgView;

}

-(void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner {
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
    [banner setAlpha:1];
    [UIView commitAnimations];

        [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint
                                  constraintWithItem:_imgView
                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                  relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                  toItem:self.view
                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                  multiplier:1.0
                                  constant:-100.0]];

}

-(void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error {
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
    [banner setAlpha:0];
    [UIView commitAnimations];

        [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint
                                  constraintWithItem:_imgView
                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                  relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                  toItem:self.view
                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                  multiplier:1.0
                                  constant:-50.0]];
}
```

Comment: Show the constraints and the error log. It will help us more.

Comment: You need to include the _full_ error that is produced, as well as any code you use to create the constraints, or a screenshot of the constraints in your storyboard. But from the sound of it, you have two contradicting constraints, which cannot possibly work out the way you desire.

Answer (score 0):

as I understand you have conflict between constraints, you should delete one of two constraint.

Comment: The error is about the bottom of the uiimageview and the uiview bottom which has no constraint that I can see in storyboard. Any other place I should be looking?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are adding a bottom constraints 2 times, once in the `-(void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner` and once in the `(void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error` methods. The constraints have different constant values (-100 and -50) so they crash.

The right way to do this would be to add the constraint only once and then in the 2 methods to change it's value.

Something like this:

In the first method where you add the trailing constraint, also add the bottom constraint one and keep a reference to it:

```
self.bottomOffsetConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint
                                  constraintWithItem:_imgView
                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                  relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                  toItem:self.view
                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                  multiplier:1.0
                                  constant:-100.0];
[self.view addConstraint:self.bottomOffsetConstraint];
```

Then in the 2 methods you change the constant:

```
-(void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner {
    [self.bottomOffsetConstraint setConstant:-50];
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
    [banner setAlpha:1];
    // You need to call this in the animation block to trigger the constraints update
    [self.view layoutIfNeeded]; 
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

-(void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error {

    [self.bottomOffsetConstraint setConstant:-50];
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
    [banner setAlpha:0];
    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

This will fix the crashing constraints and will animate the layout changes.

Let me know how it goes!

Comment: Same crash report, did you mean to put -100 in the viewDidLoadAd? When iAd banner appears the image isn't repositioned. Let me know if I can provide more code...

Comment: Hmm.. that should not happen. Could you show me in which method you add the constraint? What value should the constraint have when you start the app?

Comment: It should be -50 (lower position) when it starts and it's in viewWillAppear. My original numbers were backwards sorry for confusion. Now it starts off in the right position (lower), iads appears and it move up (nice!). If I segue back to the view the image is in the upper position and lower position. the lower one moves to the upper one.